# RedirectToAction to action in another controller not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my mvc3 POST ActionResult method, I have a portion of code like this:

```
if (button == "Save as Pdf")
{                
  RedirectToAction("getPdf", "Pdf", resultObtained);
}
```

when the user clicked on the button, it redirect the user to getPdf action in PdfController while passing the object resultObtained as well to get the PDF file downloaded via browser but the RedirectToAction itself is not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (button == "Save as Pdf")
{                
  return RedirectToAction("getPdf", "Pdf", resultObtained);
}
```

Comment: @Stafford: you saved me; was hitting my head against why redirectToAction not working. Turned out I was missing return :)