# Login with email and password control not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication

I am trying to take the email and password from my login form and see if they exist in my database.I use entity framework with local db. My register code is similar and works fine, i have some users is my database. The thing is that when i run this code for login it's not working. I put the right data ant it's not redirecting me in my AfterLogin page neither to Failed. it only returns the View (email is also the primary key of my table)

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LoginConfirm(User u)


    {

            MyDbEntities db = new MyDbEntities();
            var result = db.Users.Where(model => model.Email == u.Email
                 && model.password == u.password).FirstOrDefault();

            if (result != null)    
            {
                RedirectToAction("AfterLogin");
            }
            else    
            {
                RedirectToAction("Failed");
            }


        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What's the value of `result` when you debug?

Comment: More importantly, what are `u`'s values? What do your `User` class and your login view look like?

Comment: wait i am going to post it

Comment: Nice find @Rahul. Though it's a duplicate of [RedirectToAction to action in another controller not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090235/redirecttoaction-to-action-in-another-controller-not-working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your action method is returning a `ActionResult` and so you will have to say `return  RedirectToAction("AfterLogin");`

```
        if (result != null)    
        {
          return  RedirectToAction("AfterLogin");
        }
```